# How to calculate sum of employees late mins and Insert into another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Employees daily late minutes stored in one table(Attndate) and I want to calculate sum of Individual employees late mins then insert into another table(LateMuster) using sql server stored procedure

**And Important I want to get late mins between 2 dates like '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-08'**

> Attndate - Table

[image]

Expected Output - LateMuster-Table

> [image: LateMuster - Table]

finally I will use this table to crystal report(using vb.net)

Note :- I am Using sql server 2005, and visual studio 2005

Comment: If you only want late minutes between 2017-09-01 and 2017-09-08, why does your expected output have 31 days of columns?

Comment: @ScottHodgin '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-08' is for example, 31 means 31 days(1 month)

Comment: So, your destination table has 31 column days, but you only want your insert query to insert days 1 through 8 since you are only interested in late minutes between 2017-09-01 and 2017-09-08?  I'm assuming your destination table has your individual 'days' columns defined to allow nulls?

Comment: Yes, it can be allow nulls, Today 08-Sep-2017 so i need only from '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-08', if no values on 02-sep-2017 can store null values

Comment: And what do you want to happen tomorrow or the next day?  Now, it seems there is 'current-date' logic involved and not just two hard-coded dates.

Comment: Just Put Null values for tomorrow and next days, I want this calculation for  employees Late mins report for a month, for example If I want to get previous month report I just give '2017-08-01' and '2017-08-31'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65289/discussion-between-relax-and-scott-hodgin).

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- the question is tagged with `sql-server-2005` and according to the MSSQL documentation, CTEs and PIVOT tables are not supported until `sql-server-2008`
- the question is also tagged with `stored-procedures` so I'm guessing some procedural coding is acceptable (ie, this doesn't have to be a single query)

For this answer we'll look at populating a #temp table and then dynamically build a query to 'pivot' the data into the 31 columns/days ...

I took the liberty of adding some data for August so we'd have a wrap-around on the month, plus a couple double entries for day 1 of the month (Aug 01, Sep 01):

```
drop table if exists Attndate;

create table Attndate
(EMPCODE     int
,EMPNAME     varchar(30)
,[DATE]      date
,InTime      time
,LateMins    int);

insert into AttnDate (EMPCODE, EMPNAME,[DATE],InTime,LateMins) values
(1,'John' ,'08/01/2017','9:17', 7),
(2,'David','08/01/2017','9:18', 8),
(3,'Kumar','08/01/2017','9:12', 2),
(4,'Jack' ,'08/01/2017','9:18', 8),

(1,'John' ,'08/26/2017','9:27',17),
(2,'David','08/26/2017','9:20',10),
(3,'Kumar','08/26/2017','9:17', 7),
(4,'Jack' ,'08/26/2017','9:13', 3),

(5,'Rose' ,'08/28/2017','9:31',21),

(2,'David','08/29/2017','9:28',18),

(3,'Kumar','08/30/2017','9:23',23),

(4,'Jack' ,'08/31/2017','9:59',49),

(1,'John' ,'09/01/2017','9:30',20),
(2,'David','09/01/2017','9:25',15),
(3,'Kumar','09/01/2017','9:12', 2),
(4,'Jack' ,'09/01/2017','9:15', 5),

(5,'Rose' ,'09/02/2017','9:36',26),
(2,'David','09/02/2017','9:18', 8),
(3,'Kumar','09/02/2017','9:13', 3),
(4,'Jack' ,'09/02/2017','9:51',41),

(1,'John' ,'09/03/2017','9:30', 4),
(3,'Kumar','09/03/2017','9:30',13);
```

We'll populate our `#rollup` table with `[DATE]` converted to day of month plus `LateMins` summed up by day of month:

```
drop table if exists #rollup;

select  EMPCODE,
        EMPNAME,
        day([DATE]) as dom,
        sum(LateMins) as lm
into    #rollup
from    Attndate
where   [Date] between '2017-08-01' and '2017-09-30'
group by EMPCODE,
         EMPNAME,
         day([DATE])
```

Now we use a looping construct to build our 'pivot' query:

```
declare  @query varchar(max),
         @ctr   int

select @ctr=1,
       @query = 'select distinct r1.EMPCODE, r1.EMPNAME'

while @ctr < 32
begin
    select @query = @query + char(10) + ', (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=' + convert(varchar(2),@ctr) + ') as [' + convert(varchar(2),@ctr) + ']'
    select @ctr   = @ctr + 1
end

set @query = @query + char(10) + ', (select sum(lm) from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE) as [Total Late Mins]' + char(10) +' from  #rollup r1 order by 1,2'

print @query

execute (@query)
```

The `print @query` displays our 'pivot' query as:

```
select distinct r1.EMPCODE, r1.EMPNAME
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=1) as [1]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=2) as [2]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=3) as [3]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=4) as [4]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=5) as [5]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=6) as [6]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=7) as [7]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=8) as [8]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=9) as [9]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=10) as [10]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=11) as [11]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=12) as [12]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=13) as [13]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=14) as [14]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=15) as [15]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=16) as [16]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=17) as [17]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=18) as [18]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=19) as [19]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=20) as [20]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=21) as [21]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=22) as [22]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=23) as [23]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=24) as [24]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=25) as [25]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=26) as [26]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=27) as [27]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=28) as [28]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=29) as [29]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=30) as [30]
, (select lm from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=31) as [31]
, (select sum(lm) from #rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE) as [Total Late Mins]
 from  #rollup r1 order by 1,2
```

And the `execute (@query)` statement generates our 'pivot' table:

```
EMPCODE | EMPNAME |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |   15 |   16 |   17 |   18 |   19 |   20 |   21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |   25 |   26 |   27 |   28 |   29 |   30 |   31 | Total Late Mins
------- | ------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---------------
      1 | John    |   27 | null |    4 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   17 | null | null | null | null | null |              48
      2 | David   |   23 |    8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   10 | null | null |   18 | null | null |              59
      3 | Kumar   |    4 |    3 |   13 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |    7 | null | null | null |   23 | null |              50
      4 | Jack    |   13 |   41 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |    3 | null | null | null | null |   49 |             106
      5 | Rose    | null |   26 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   21 | null | null | null |              47
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f30bee6df94d0a3575c752cce3640756) for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside potential limitations of `sql-server-2005`, here's a solution that dynamically builds a 'pivot' query anchored by a CTE.

I took the liberty of adding some data for August so we'd have a wrap-around on the month, plus a couple double entries for day 1 of the month (Aug 01, Sep 01):

```
drop table if exists Attndate;

create table Attndate
(EMPCODE     int
,EMPNAME     varchar(30)
,[DATE]      date
,InTime      time
,LateMins    int);

insert into AttnDate (EMPCODE, EMPNAME,[DATE],InTime,LateMins) values
(1,'John' ,'08/01/2017','9:17', 7),
(2,'David','08/01/2017','9:18', 8),
(3,'Kumar','08/01/2017','9:12', 2),
(4,'Jack' ,'08/01/2017','9:18', 8),

(1,'John' ,'08/26/2017','9:27',17),
(2,'David','08/26/2017','9:20',10),
(3,'Kumar','08/26/2017','9:17', 7),
(4,'Jack' ,'08/26/2017','9:13', 3),

(5,'Rose' ,'08/28/2017','9:31',21),

(2,'David','08/29/2017','9:28',18),

(3,'Kumar','08/30/2017','9:23',23),

(4,'Jack' ,'08/31/2017','9:59',49),


(1,'John' ,'09/01/2017','9:30',20),
(2,'David','09/01/2017','9:25',15),
(3,'Kumar','09/01/2017','9:12', 2),
(4,'Jack' ,'09/01/2017','9:15', 5),

(5,'Rose' ,'09/02/2017','9:36',26),
(2,'David','09/02/2017','9:18', 8),
(3,'Kumar','09/02/2017','9:13', 3),
(4,'Jack' ,'09/02/2017','9:51',41),

(1,'John' ,'09/03/2017','9:30', 4),
(3,'Kumar','09/03/2017','9:30',13);
```

Dynamically build our 'pivot' query with the assistance of a CTE:

```
declare  @query varchar(max),
         @ctr   int

select @ctr=1,
       @query = 
'with rollup as
(select  EMPCODE,
         EMPNAME,
         day([DATE]) as dom,
         sum(LateMins) as lm
 from    Attndate
 where   [Date] between ''2017-08-01'' and ''2017-09-30''
 group by EMPCODE,
          EMPNAME,
          day([DATE]))
select distinct r1.EMPCODE, r1.EMPNAME'

while @ctr < 32
begin
    select @query = @query + char(10) + ', (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=' + convert(varchar(2),@ctr) + ') as [' + convert(varchar(2),@ctr) + ']'
    select @ctr   = @ctr + 1
end

select @query = @query + char(10) + ', (select sum(lm) from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE) as [Total Late Mins]' + char(10) +' from  rollup r1 order by 1,2'

print @query

execute (@query)
```

- the CTE (rollup) converts `[DATE]`'s into days of the month (`dom`), as well as sums up `LateMins` (`lm`)
- the sub-query `(rollup r2)` gives us the final column of our result set `[Total Late Mins]`

The `print @query` displays our 'pivot' query as::

```
with rollup as
(select  EMPCODE,
         EMPNAME,
         day([DATE]) as dom,
         sum(LateMins) as lm
 from    Attndate
 where   [Date] between '2017-08-01' and '2017-09-30'
 group by EMPCODE,
          EMPNAME,
          day([DATE]))
select distinct r1.EMPCODE, r1.EMPNAME
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=1) as [1]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=2) as [2]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=3) as [3]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=4) as [4]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=5) as [5]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=6) as [6]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=7) as [7]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=8) as [8]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=9) as [9]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=10) as [10]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=11) as [11]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=12) as [12]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=13) as [13]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=14) as [14]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=15) as [15]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=16) as [16]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=17) as [17]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=18) as [18]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=19) as [19]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=20) as [20]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=21) as [21]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=22) as [22]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=23) as [23]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=24) as [24]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=25) as [25]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=26) as [26]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=27) as [27]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=28) as [28]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=29) as [29]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=30) as [30]
, (select lm from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE and r2.dom=31) as [31]
, (select sum(lm) from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=r1.EMPCODE) as [Total Late Mins]
 from  rollup r1 order by 1,2
```

And the `execute (@query)` statement generates our 'pivot' table:

```
EMPCODE | EMPNAME |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |   15 |   16 |   17 |   18 |   19 |   20 |   21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |   25 |   26 |   27 |   28 |   29 |   30 |   31 | Total Late Mins
------- | ------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---------------
      1 | John    |   27 | null |    4 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   17 | null | null | null | null | null |              48
      2 | David   |   23 |    8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   10 | null | null |   18 | null | null |              59
      3 | Kumar   |    4 |    3 |   13 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |    7 | null | null | null |   23 | null |              50
      4 | Jack    |   13 |   41 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |    3 | null | null | null | null |   49 |             106
      5 | Rose    | null |   26 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   21 | null | null | null |              47
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=eac23c63bc9c438dc3a0b712734f6494) for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside potential limitations of `sql-server-2005`, here's a solution that uses a CTE and a PIVOT statement.

I took the liberty of adding some data for August so we'd have a wrap-around on the month, plus a couple double entries for day 1 of the month (Aug 01, Sep 01):

```
drop table if exists Attndate;

create table Attndate
(EMPCODE     int
,EMPNAME     varchar(30)
,[DATE]      date
,InTime      time
,LateMins    int);

insert into AttnDate (EMPCODE, EMPNAME,[DATE],InTime,LateMins) values
(1,'John' ,'08/01/2017','9:17', 7),
(2,'David','08/01/2017','9:18', 8),
(3,'Kumar','08/01/2017','9:12', 2),
(4,'Jack' ,'08/01/2017','9:18', 8),

(1,'John' ,'08/26/2017','9:27',17),
(2,'David','08/26/2017','9:20',10),
(3,'Kumar','08/26/2017','9:17', 7),
(4,'Jack' ,'08/26/2017','9:13', 3),

(5,'Rose' ,'08/28/2017','9:31',21),

(2,'David','08/29/2017','9:28',18),

(3,'Kumar','08/30/2017','9:23',23),

(4,'Jack' ,'08/31/2017','9:59',49),


(1,'John' ,'09/01/2017','9:30',20),
(2,'David','09/01/2017','9:25',15),
(3,'Kumar','09/01/2017','9:12', 2),
(4,'Jack' ,'09/01/2017','9:15', 5),

(5,'Rose' ,'09/02/2017','9:36',26),
(2,'David','09/02/2017','9:18', 8),
(3,'Kumar','09/02/2017','9:13', 3),
(4,'Jack' ,'09/02/2017','9:51',41),

(1,'John' ,'09/03/2017','9:30', 4),
(3,'Kumar','09/03/2017','9:30',13);
```

The CTE/PIVOT query:

```
with rollup as
(select  EMPCODE,
         EMPNAME,
         day([DATE]) as dom,
         sum(LateMins) as lm
 from    Attndate
 where   [Date] between '2017-08-01' and '2017-09-30'
 group by EMPCODE,
          EMPNAME,
          day([DATE]))

select EMPCODE,
       EMPNAME,
       [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31], 
       (select sum(r2.lm) from rollup r2 where r2.EMPCODE=pt.EMPCODE) as [Total Late Mins]
from   (select EMPCODE, EMPNAME,lm,dom from rollup r1) as dt
        pivot
        (sum(lm) for dom in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])
       ) as pt
order by 1,2
```

- the CTE (`rollup`) converts `[DATE]`'s into days of the month (`dom`), as well as sums up `LateMins` (`lm`)
- for the `PIVOT` clause we'll issue a `sum(lm)`; this doesn't change our results but allows us to meet the `PIVOT'`s requirement for an aggregate function
- the sub-query (`rollup r2`) gives us the final column of our result set `[Total Late Mins]`

And the results of the query:

```
EMPCODE | EMPNAME |    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |   11 |   12 |   13 |   14 |   15 |   16 |   17 |   18 |   19 |   20 |   21 |   22 |   23 |   24 |   25 |   26 |   27 |   28 |   29 |   30 |   31 | Total Late Mins
------- | ------- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---------------
      1 | John    |   27 | null |    4 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   17 | null | null | null | null | null |              48
      2 | David   |   23 |    8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   10 | null | null |   18 | null | null |              59
      3 | Kumar   |    4 |    3 |   13 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |    7 | null | null | null |   23 | null |              50
      4 | Jack    |   13 |   41 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |    3 | null | null | null | null |   49 |             106
      5 | Rose    | null |   26 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |   21 | null | null | null |              47
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8c5c056b1a2ff533b802264312461b78) for this answer.